# Dismiss a UIPopoverController

Tags: uikit, ios4, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

Is there a right mechanism to dismiss a UIPopoverController from the controller that I've passed in the ctor?

```
_popover = new UIPopoverController(myController);
```

From myController instance, I would dismiss the popover but I can't find any system UIViewController property to do that.

A fix is to create a public property in MyController class of type UIPopoverController and then set it when I create the _popover instance. But I think it's not so good.

```
myController.PopOverProperty = _popover;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_popover.Dismiss(true);
```

Do you need this?

Comment: yes, but from myController instance. Using myController.PopOverProperty.Dismiss(true), works. But I would like to know if there is a better solution to hide the popup inside the controller.

Comment: There are definitely better design choices, but may be overkill if this is your only situation.  I would use an IoC container of some kind and subclass the UIPopoverController, but those are some high concepts for iPhone apps.  A simpler approach would be to create a HidePopOver() method so you don't expose the entire popover to the outside world.